Appropriate stats model for time data with an upper limit?
I'm struggling to settle on a statistical approach for a portion of my dataset. Any thoughts/insight would be appreciated.
Subjects (divided into two categorical groups) were given up to an hour to play a game each day for multiple days. If they did not engage with the game for 5 minutes, the game would terminate early.
My dependent variable captures the amount of time each subject spent playing the game each day. However, it's capped at 1 hour as the game would automatically terminate. Further, subjects had less than an hour of total gameplay only if they were timed out by inactivity.
I want to build a model akin to 'Gameplay_time ~ Date * Group + (1|Subject)' but with an upper bound of 1 hour.
My primary question is whether there are group differences in the amount of time played on any of the days tested.

What do you think is the appropriate approach to this dataset? My initial thought was a one-inflated beta regression, but this resulted in seemingly spurious results.
Is it better to split the question? For example, would it be better to do a Chi-Square test of 'Timed_Out' (Y/N) Vs 'Group' (two levels). Then, if insignificant, remove the subjects that played for 1 hour and fit a GLMM on the reduced dataset.


You need a form of censored regression, because what you describe appear to be right-censored responses.  Unless censoring rarely occurs, Beta regression would appear to be a poor choice (and even then wouldn't be the first thing to consider unless it's the only method you know).  // Splitting the question is an intriguing idea, but why not investigate standard survival time methods first (because they are likely to make best use of all the data)?

@whuber Apologies for my slow reply. Your advice was perfect and I'm extremely grateful to you for steering my attention. I ended up using a Cox proportional hazards model. Thanks so much!

@StatsNewbie: Then you can answer your own question so as it will not linger on as unresolved!

Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen! I wasn't sure if it was a metric of importance here and didn't want to steal the valour from whuber. Will "answer" & close it now. :)

Adding more details per mod request:
As @whuber commented and according to my subsequent reading, a censored regression model is an appropriate way to make use of my entire dataset, including subjects that were timed out and those that completed the full hour. That way there is no need to split the data as proposed in my second query.
In simple terms, a censored regression model is capable of comparing the rates of events within your dataset across a given study period, as I was alluding to do in my primary query. Importantly, it is also able to handle a dataset where the event of interest does not occur for all participants within the study timeline (this is the "censored" part of the model).
In my case, the "event" was participants being timed out and the study period was the hour of possible 'Gameplay_time'. The Cox proportional hazards model was an appropriate form of censored regression model as my response variable is time-to-event data.
Hope this is sufficient to classify as an "answer"! :)
